# What other types can <script> have?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been wondering about this for quite a while, finally going to find out ;)

We have `<script type="text/javascript">...</script>`.

I have never seen any type but `text/javascript`, and sometimes the type attribute is even missing, defaulting to javascript anyway.

*So, the question:*

Is there any other use for the `type` attribute - any other script we can use?

Comment: Good info here, http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html

Comment: IIRC in HTML5 if you omit it it's assumed to be JavaScript. It's allowed to be any valid MIME type but obviously it either needs to be either something your target browsers will understand or a data chunk you're going to reference from other script.

Comment: Not really that good, and does not even provide the answer - if it isn't hidden somewhere..

Comment: `<script>` tags are also often used to store configuration or templates informations using an `x-` type e.g. `text/x-template`, `text/x-config` because this is a nice way to store information that would not be indexed by search-engines and it is easier to store larger data there then in e.g. an `data-` attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Available types are:

- text/javascript
- text/ecmascript
- application/javascript
- application/ecmascript

If you don't specify `type`, `text/javascript` is used.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Comment: Plus, e.g., anything else that the developer wants - such as `type="text/template"`

Comment: Plus anything a specific browser wants to accept as well, e.g. application/vbscript or application/dart

Comment: @AD7six if I stuff this "anything else" there, what good can that be for? Can javascript somehow access this chunk of data?

Comment: @MightyPork it's common to use script tags for anything which 1) you do not want the browser to interpret 2) to be available to other resources/scripts at run time. A common example is [backbone view templates](http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-view/) where the script tag contents is accessible as a string.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Shivan Raptor's response:

Sometimes you can find `type="text/template"`. This type isn't understand by the browser so the browser will simply ignore it. This allows you to put anything in there.

This type is commonly used by templating libraries as [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own languages and tools that evaluate code in tags.  For example, the coffeescript client script ships with support for processing `text/coffeescript` tags.

Also, IE supports `text/vbscript`

Comment: It would be allowed (probably - is that the correct Content Type for PHP?) but that doesn't necessarily mean that any client would run it or do anything with it.